# Numbered Lists not working using PHP, CKEditor and Outlook

Tags: php, html, outlook, format, ckeditor

When i write a text using CKEditor in my application and format it as a numbered list it is displayed correct like

```
Answers to your questions:
  1. First Answer
  2. Second Answer
```

and the html behind is

```
<p><span style="color:#1f497d">Answers to your questions:</span></p>

<ol>
    <li><span style="color:#1f497d">First Answer</span></li>
    <li><span style="color:#1f497d">Second Answer</span></li>
</ol>
```

but when I send this text in an email outlook ( my current Version is 2016) is not showing the numbers and the text of the numbered list items get formatted in a smaller font size then the other text as shown in the image below.

[image]

When i check the code behind with "show source" it shows up like this

```
<p style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-size: 100%;vertical-align: bottom;font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;line-height:1.2"><span style="color:#1f497d">Answers to your questions</span></p>

<ol style="margin-right:0px;margin: 0;padding: 0;font-size: 100%;vertical-align: bottom;font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;line-height:1.2">
    <li style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;line-height:1.4;vertical-align:middle;font-size:12px"><span style="color:#1f497d">First Answer</span></li>
    <li style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;line-height:1.4;vertical-align:middle;font-size:12px"><span style="color:#1f497d">Second Answer</span></li>
</ol>
```

Does Outlook maybe not understand the  tag or have you got any oder suggestion for me what could be the problem in this case?

I appreciate any help!

Comment: This is definitely a duplicate of the question you commented on earlier. You can use the same JSFiddle / code I posted previously to get this - you just need to replace the &bullet; with your numbers and adjust any sort of spacing.

Edited to add link to duplicate: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22053157/1308792

Comment: Furthermore - outlook absolutely doesn't understand OL / UL tags. It also adds padding to paragraph tags, so I would avoid using those as well. I'm going to post an answer with code and updated fiddle as my previous answer doesn't address text formatting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trouble with ol and ul tags in email sent with Outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13021345/trouble-with-ol-and-ul-tags-in-email-sent-with-outlook)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a JS fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/GHC7m/81/

Outlook does not understand OL / UL tags, and also will add extra padding to P tags. In order to format the text you have, I've turned those into div tags. These need to be included around any text, including text within a TD. Outlook also has some oddities around padding / margin vs how other email rendering clients handle those properties if I recall correctly, but you should search out more info on that on SO.

Don't ever try to apply padding or margins to your TD or TR tags, it will mess up your table. You should also add your font-family, font-size, and line-height on all of your divs.

```html
    <div style="font-family: Times, georgia, serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 17px;color:#1f497d">Answers to your questions:</div>
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr><td width="30" align="center" valign="top">
                <div style="font-family: Times, georgia, serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 17px;color:#1f497d;text-align:center;">1.</div>
            </td>
            <td width="200" align="left" valign="top">
                <div style="font-family: Times, georgia, serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 17px;color:#1f497d;">
                    First answer 
                </div>
             </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td width="30" align="center" valign="top">
                <div style="font-family: Times, georgia, serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 17px;color:#1f497d;text-align: center;">2.</div>
            </td>
            <td width="200" align="left" valign="top">
                <div style="font-family: Times, georgia, serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 17px;color:#1f497d">
                    Second answer
                  </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: First of all thanks for your detailed answer. I already got the problem mentioned in the other post that i should use tables instead of OL and UL, the problem is that the CKEditor provides multiple Options to format a text. One of them is to create Ordered Lists and Bullet Lists and it gives them the default tags OL/UL.
For the moment i fixed the problem with replacing the built html with excactly what outlook expects (i got it by creating a Ordered List with Outlook and checking the source) but actually id like the option to append a css that makes the ol tag work.

Comment: Can you clarify that? I am reading that you can't get OL/UL to render correctly as you use the source code Outlook outputs and that works, but that you want CSS to make the OL tag work, and those statements are a bit contradictory.

Comment: At the moment i set the class of the LI elements to 'MsoListParagraph' using jquery since i saw that this is what outlook does if you let it generate a list and with this option its working to display the list. But what i actually want to do is to get the normal tags working with some styling or something like that.

Comment: If it's displaying correctly with class="MsoListParagraph", that means you are using preset CSS styling included by Outlook and that it's working, and you shouldn't need to do anything further.